# How do I grab random elements on python from paired lists?

Tags: python, list, random

I tried to compare drop height versus rebound height and have some data here:

```
drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]
```

I want to select 5 random data points off of these variables, so I tried

```
smol_drop_heights = []
smol_rebound_heights = []

for each in range(0,5):
     smol_drop_heights.append(drop_heights[randint(0, 9)])
     smol_rebound_heights.append(rebound_heights[randint(0, 9)])
print(smol_drop_heights)
print(smol_rebound_heights)
```

When they print, they print different sets of data, and sometimes even repeat data, how do I fix this?

```
[0.8, 1.6, 0.6, 0.2, 0.12]
[1.02, 1.15, 0.88, 0.88, 0.6]
```

Here is a sample output, where you can see .88 is repeated.

Comment: Can you show what you would expect?  Do they need to be paired in any  way?

Comment: Yes I want them to be paired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call randint, it gives a different random number each time. To solve this you would need to save an index variable, to a random number, each time the code loops, so that you add the same random variable each time.

```
for each in range(0, 4):  
    index = randint(0, 9)  
    smol_drop_heights.append(drop_heights[index])  
    smol_rebound_heights.append(rebound_heights[index])  
print(smol_drop_heights)  
print(smol_rebound_heights)
```

To solve the problem about repeats, just check if the lists already have the variable you want to add, you could do it with either variable, as neither of them have repeats in them, and since there may be repeats, a for loop will not be sufficient, so you will have to repeat until the lists are full.
So my final solution is:

```
while True:  
    index = randint(0, 9)  
    if drop_heights[index] not in smol_drop_heights:  
        smol_drop_heights.append(drop_heights[index])  
        smol_rebound_heights.append(rebound_heights[index])  
    if len(smol_drop_heights) == 4:  
        break  
print(smol_drop_heights)  
print(smol_rebound_heights)
```

And since you may want to arrange those value in order, you may do this:

```
smol_drop_heights = []  
smol_rebound_heights = []  

while True:  
    index = randint(0, 9)  
    if drop_heights[index] not in smol_drop_heights:  
        smol_drop_heights.append(drop_heights[index])  
        smol_rebound_heights.append(rebound_heights[index])  
    if len(smol_drop_heights) == 4:  
        smol_drop_heights.sort()  
        smol_rebound_heights.sort()  
        break  
print(smol_drop_heights)  
print(smol_rebound_heights)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be:

```
drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]
indices = [*range(len(drop_heights))]
from random import shuffle
shuffle(indices)
smol_drop_heights = []
smol_rebound_heights = []
for each in indices:
    smol_drop_heights.append(drop_heights[each])
    smol_rebound_heights.append(rebound_heights[each])
print(smol_drop_heights)
print(smol_rebound_heights)
```

Output:

```
[1.7, 0.8, 1.6, 1.2, 0.2, 0.4, 1.4, 2.0, 1.0, 0.6]
[1.34, 0.6, 1.15, 0.88, 0.16, 0.3, 1.02, 1.51, 0.74, 0.46]
```

Or, much shorter:

```
from random import sample

drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]

paired = [*zip(drop_heights, rebound_heights)]
smol_drop_heights, smol_rebound_heights = zip(*sample(paired,5))

print(smol_drop_heights[:5])
print(smol_rebound_heights[:5])
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to avoid repetitions and keep the data points paired and randomly sort the pairs:

```
from random import random

drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]

pairs = list(sorted(zip(drop_heights, rebound_heights), key=lambda _: random()))[:5]

smol_drop_heights = [d for d, _ in pairs]
smol_rebound_heights = [r for _, r in pairs]
```

Comment: What do the last 2 lines mean, and the lines about pairs =...?

Comment: They separate the pairs back into a drop and a rebound height by iterating over them, and taking one the first element, and the other time the second element.

Answer (score 2):

Here"s what I would do.

```
import random
import numpy as np
k=5
drop_heights = np.array([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0])
rebound_heights = np.array([0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51])
idx = random.sample(range(len(drop_heights )), k)

print(drop_heights[idx])
print(rebound_heights [idx])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try shuffling and then use the `index` of the original items like,

```
>>> drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
>>> rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]
>>> 
>>> import random 
>>> d = drop_heights[:] # keep a copy to get index for making pairs later
>>> random.shuffle(drop_heights)
>>> # iterate through the new list and get the index of the item 
>>> # from the original lists
>>> nd, nr = zip(*[(x,rebound_heights[d.index(x)]) for x in drop_heights])
>>> nd[:5]
(1.4, 0.6, 1.7, 0.2, 1.0)
>>> nr[:5]
(1.02, 0.46, 1.34, 0.16, 0.74)
```

or just use `operator.itemgetter` and `random.sample` like,

```
>>> drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
>>> rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]
>>> 
>>> import random, operator
>>> indexes = random.sample(range(len(drop_heights)), 5)
>>> indexes
[5, 0, 4, 7, 3]
>>> f = operator.itemgetter(*indexes)
>>> f(drop_heights)
(1.2, 0.2, 1.0, 1.6, 0.8)
>>> f(rebound_heights)
(0.88, 0.16, 0.74, 1.15, 0.6)
```

Comment: too sophisticated, yet operator.itemgetter(*indexes) does have an quiet elegance. worth an upvote

Comment: Thanks. The only time i liked `operator.itemgetter` :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you want to do *two* things, pair your lists. The idiomatic way to do this is to use `zip`:

```
drop_heights = [0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.7, 2.0]
rebound_heights = [0.16, 0.30, 0.46, 0.6, 0.74, 0.88, 1.02, 1.15, 1.34, 1.51]
paired = list(zip(drop_heights, rebound_heights))
```

Then, you want to *sample* five pairs from this. So use `random.sample`:

```
sampled = random.sample(paired, 5)
```

Finally, if you need them to be in seperate lists (you probably don't, but if you must), you can unpack it like this:

```
smol_drop_heights, smol_rebound_heights = zip(*sampled)
```

You can actually just do this in all at once, although it might become a bit unreadable:

```
smol_drop_heights, smol_rebound_heights = zip(*random.sample(list(zip(drop_heights, rebound_heights)), 5))
```